# DropDownList in a GridView to bind the selected value of DropDown in TextBox inside a GridView in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

i have a DropDownList in a GridView and want to bind the selected value of DropDown in TextBox inside a GridView to pass the selected value in query string in asp.net c#
please help me to guide and code of SelectedIndexChanged of DropDownList 
[screenshot of GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mwf8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach a method to the SelectedIndexChanged event on each child dropdown, either in the markup, either using a AddHandler in the RowDataBound event of your gridview

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="redirect" />
```

Save the value wherever you want (hidden or textbox) when the selected item is changed

```
protected void ddlSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    txt1.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;
}
```

And use this value when clicking the button

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx?q=" + txt1.Text);
}
```

or use jquery onChange event atttached to the dropdowns ?

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
})
```